# Emscripten: "allocating an object of abstract class type" error when creating wrapper to allow subclasses

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten, embind

Consider the following contrived example:

```cpp
class IBar {
    void qux() = 0;
};

class IFoo {
    void execute(const IBar &bar) = 0;
};

struct FooWrapper : public wrapper<IFoo> {
    EMSCRIPTEN_WRAPPER(FooWrapper);

    void execute(const IBar &bar) override {
        return call<void>("execute", bar);
    }
};

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(IFoo) {
    class_<IFoo>("IFoo")
        .function("execute", &IFoo::execute, allow_raw_pointers(), pure_virtual())
        .allow_subclass<FooWrapper>("FooWrapper");
}
```

If I try to compile this code, I get an error because I'm trying to "allocating an object of abstract class type `IBar`."

```
/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include/emscripten/wire.h:348:28: error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'IBar'
                return new T(v);
```

Obviously `IBar` is abstract, but that shouldn't matter since `execute` is taking a reference to an `IBar` object. And it appears that `emscripten::call` is trying to instantiate `IBar` for some unknown reason.

In my real-world code, I can't change the signature of `IFoo::execute`.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this issue?

Comment: You will likely have to derive a concrete class from `IBar` and then bind to that so it is the type that `call()` creates. Similar to what you are doing with `FooWrapper`. The derived object will still be passable to `IFoo::execute()` without changing its signature. Polymorphism 101.

Comment: Try `call<void>("execute", std::cref(bar))`; it may be doing marshalling of some kind.

Comment: `std::cref` did the trick. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont you really should post an answer. The approach using `std::cref` also helped me with a class ref that has a deleted copy constructor.

Comment: @MikeLischke Feel free to write one up.  At the time I was deep into `EMSCRIPTEN_BINDING`s stuff, but today I couldn't reliably turn my suggestion into an answer without further work.